# Автоматический масштаб всего контента под размер окна

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка, масштабирование

Как сделать, что вся страница и весь ее контент атоматически подгонялся под размер окна, т.е. чтоб не было скролов. пропорции сохранять не обязательно. Страница может растягиваться как резина..

Comment: А язык какой? И страница где? Веб? Настольное приложение? Мобильное приложение?

Comment: это веб сайт php

Comment: Это называется адаптивная верстка - поищите информацию про это

Comment: Зачем писать заглавными буквами. Мы прекрасно видим.

Comment: я искал, но к сожалению не нашел нужную инфу. там в основном говорится о том, как адаптировать сайт под различные устройства, но меня интересует, чтоб сайт растягивался по рамерам окна как резина

Comment: Я так понял вам нужна резиновая верстка. Она делается при помощи не точно указания ширины блоков (в пикселях), а в процентах. Но сейчас это считается плохой практикой, так как резина очень плохо выглядит на устройствах с малым разрешением экрана.
Но если очень надо, то [вот видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQlkyQpy4hk) про резиновую верстку.

Comment: да. мне нужна именно резина. Просмотрел видео. Спасибо! Но к сожалению там растягивается только ширина. сейчас попробую помудрить с высотой

Comment: @AlexAnder [Статья](https://learn.javascript.ru/height-percent) на тему высоты в процентах. Но при резиновой верстки резина заключается только в изменении ширины, а не высоты.

Comment: @AlexAnder [Вот](https://jsfiddle.net/zbL57zbo/1/) пример кода, как раз который вам нужен

Comment: спасибо! ввожу эти параметры, но к сожалению высота не растягивается, в отличии от ширины

Comment: @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
вот код css img{
 float: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

Comment: @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
img{
 float: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>HOME</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<img src="Lighthouse.jpg" width="1000" height="1000"  alt=""/>
</body>

</html>

Comment: Интересен тот факт, что всё заработало, как только я открыл с траницу в Chrome.

Comment: теперь вопрос как адаптировать ее под все браузеры, т.к. IE не реагирует на высоту

Answer (score 2):

Используйте для измерений основых блоков страницы единицы `vw` (означает `viewport width`) для горизонтальных измерений и `vh` (означает `viewport height`) для вертикальных измерений, где

- `1vw` означает 1% от ширины экрана
- `1vh` означает 1% от высоты экрана.

Comment: а как правильно эти параметры записывать? в стилях?

Comment: @AlexAnder Да, к примеру, `width: 50vw`, `font-size: calc(1vh + 10px)`, `margin-left: 0.05vw` и т.д.

Comment: [вот](https://jsfiddle.net/zbL57zbo/1/) мне что порекомендовали. все заработало, но только в Chrome. но в IE на высоту не реагирует

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zbL57zbo/1/

Comment: Ну я вижу, что в IE работает. Высота уменьшается при уменьшении высоты экрана.